# How can I load a UserControl by specifying a string value?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls

I have some `UserControl`s named a1, a2, b1, b2... and I want to load one of them depending of the value of two variables. For example, if `var1 = a`, `var2 = 1`, the `UserControl` named `a1` will be loaded.

Is there a way of doing this? Perhaps some other alternate approach?

A `switch` statement is not a viable option here, because there will be like 200 different UserControls.

Answer (score 3):

You can use .NET Reflection to load a control by its `String` value.

you can use some code like this to create the object on the fly.

```
using System.Reflection;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //this is the full namespace name of UserControl.
            // you could use something like String.Format("WpfApplication1.{0}", "uc1") to put in a function and pass through.
            string ucName = "WpfApplication1.uc1";

            Type newType = Type.GetType("WpfApplication1.uc1", true, true);

            object o = Activator.CreateInstance(newType);

            //Use the object to how ever you like from here on wards.


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me I just needed to add something like `stkPanel.Children.Add(UIElment o);` to dynamically load up my user control when I clicked the button that had the name of my user control in it

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to create the `UserControl` instance from string name of the type.

But you would better solve this with styling or control templates - these are both great tools to reduce amount of code and its complexity in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

A powerful possibility is to use [XamlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx) to create your controls.

In your example this is not a desired, but a big advantage of using the xaml-reader is that you can also initialize properties of your control during initialization through the xamlReader.